# Only the final Array list I'm adding is cloned to all elements of the 2 Dimensional ArrayList.

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have created a program to illustrate the essence of the problem.

I want the final twoDim ArrayList to be [[a], [a,b], [a,b,c]] where a, b and c are strings.

I want to keep editing the temp ArrayList and when I have added the strings I want to temp, I want to add temp to twoDim.

Here is the demo code, you can uncomment the prints to see twoDim at different stages of the process.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDim = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i=0, j=0;


    //System.out.println(twoDim);
    temp.add("a");
    twoDim.add(temp);
    //System.out.println(twoDim);


    temp.clear();
    //System.out.println(twoDim);
    temp.add("a");
    temp.add("b");
    twoDim.add(temp);
    //System.out.println(twoDim);

    temp.clear();
    //System.out.println(twoDim);
    temp.add("a");
    temp.add("b");
    temp.add("c");
    twoDim.add(temp);


    System.out.println(twoDim);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The list isn't "cloned" at all. You are adding the same instance of `ArrayList` three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `temp.clear();` is not enough. You have to create a new `ArrayList` instance for each element of the outer `ArrayList`.
Otherwise, your outer `ArrayList` would contain the same inner `ArrayList` instance multiple times.

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

int i=0, j=0;

//System.out.println(twoDim);
temp.add("a");
twoDim.add(temp);
//System.out.println(twoDim);

temp = new ArrayList<String>();
//System.out.println(twoDim);
temp.add("a");
temp.add("b");
twoDim.add(temp);
//System.out.println(twoDim);

temp = new ArrayList<String>();
//System.out.println(twoDim);
temp.add("a");
temp.add("b");
temp.add("c");
twoDim.add(temp);
```

Comment: I tried that Eran. In that case, my final twoDim was [[], [], [a,b,c]]

Comment: Did you replace each call to `temp.clear()` with `temp = new ArrayList<String>();`?

Comment: I'm sorry Eran, I tried it again and it worked. Thanks!